# Bash Script Nested IF loop after ELSE not running (error: syntax error near unexpected token `else')

Tags: bash, syntax

I am trying to run the below code as a Bash script, but getting an unexpected token error. I can't seem to find anything wrong with the syntax. Any ideas as to what may be wrong? Thanks! Mana.

```
#!/bin/bash

START=1
END=632

c=$START
n=1  #1-node
t=1  #iterator
d=8  #days
h=00 #hours
m=00 #mins
s=00 #secs
while [[ $c -le $END ]]
do
     sed "s/nCPU/${c}/g;s/nNode/${n}/g" nCPUs.sh > ${c}CPUs.sh

     if [ $c -lt 16 ]
     then
         ((d = d / t))
         ((t = t + 1)
         sed "s/nDD/${d}/g;s/nHH/${h}/g;s/nMM/${m}/g;s/nSS/${s}/g" nCPUs.sh > ${c}CPUs.sh
         ((c = c * 2))
         ((n = 1))
     else
         if [ $c -lt 208 ]
         then
             ((d = d / t))
             ((t = t + 1)
             sed "s/nDD/${d}/g;s/nHH/${h}/g;s/nMM/${m}/g;s/nSS/${s}/g" nCPUs.sh > ${c}CPUs.sh
         else
             sed "s/nDD/0/g;s/nHH/00/g;s/nMM/30/g;s/nSS/30/g" nCPUs.sh > ${c}CPUs.sh
         fi
         ((c = c + 16))
         ((n = c / 16))
     fi
done
```

Error:

```
line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
line 24: `     else '
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: You forgot a closing `)` in `((t = t + 1))`.

Comment: it was the missing bracket afterall! Thanks @chepner and the spellcheck helped, great tool thanks for sharing Cyrus